# How to compute $T'=\{n + 1 - i : i \in T \}$ for lexicographic ordering?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinatorial-proofs

I have a question that came up during one of my combinatorial algorithm lectures, and could use some help. One of the theorems our book provides states that:

> Let $S$ consist of all $k$-element subsets of the $n$-set $S=\{1,\dots,n\}$. Suppose that $\operatorname{rank}_L$ denotes rank in the lexicographic ordering, and $\operatorname{rank}_C$ denotes rank in the co-lexicographic ordering. Then, for any $k$-set $T\in S$, we have $$\operatorname{rank}_L(T)+\operatorname{rank}_C(T')=\binom{n}{k}-1,$$ where $T'=\{n+1-i : i \in T \}$.

There was also an example provided where one subset $T=\{1,2,3\}$ had the corresponding $T'=\{3,4,5\}$, and I'm not entirely sure how this conclusion was reached. In this example $n=5$ and $k=3$.

How was $T'$ computed in this instance, and what would $n$ and $i$ be in the equation for $T'$?

Comment: Should that be $T'=\{n-i+1:i\in T\}?$

Comment: @saulspatz in the textbook I'm using it has the formula as $T'=\{n + 1 - i : i \in T \}$

Comment: That looks like a typo to me.  If you use the formula I suggest, you'll see how to compute $T'.$

Comment: @saulspatz just confirmed that the textbook did have a typo! I'll fix my post accordingly. Still, what would $i$ be? For example, for the set $\{1,2,3\}$, would $n$ be 5, and $i$ be 1? That still wouldn't yield $\{3,4,5\}$

Comment: "$\left\{n+1-i : i \in T\right\}$" is an instance of [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#More_complex_expressions_on_the_left_side_of_the_notation). Speaking in dynamical terms: you let $i$ run through $T$ and write down the resulting values of $n+1-i$; then you pack these resulting values into a set. So for $T = \left\{1,2,3\right\}$ and $n = 5$, you write down the values $5,4,3$ (obtained for $i$ being $1,2,3$, respectively) and pack them into a set; the resulting set is $\left\{5,4,3\right\} = \left\{3,4,5\right\}$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg thank you!